# If $ \det A$ is nonzero then $A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The problem is prove if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with $\det A\neq 0$, $$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A} \begin{pmatrix}C_{1,1}&...&C_{n,1}\\C_{1,2}&...&C_{n,2}\\\vdots\\C_{1,n}&...&C_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}$$ where $C_{i,j}$ is the $i,j$ th cofactor.

I am not sure if I should prove that $A$ is invertible first, but it seems that if I can prove the problem I can prove $A$'s invertibility. I am quite lost after thinking for a while. Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: The proof is a computation, albeit bothersome.

Comment: I'm sure the homework assumes that "$\det{A}\neq 0$" implies "A^{-1} exists" (and vice versa) is already known but wants just to prove the formula. To prove the formula, you might think about the Cramer's rule first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive this using Cramer's rule. However, once you have the formula in hand and wish to prove it, you need only know about expanding a determinant in cofactors:
$$\det(A) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}C_{ij} \qquad\text{for any } i.$$
So the diagonal entries of the product of $A$ and your given matrix are $1$. To see that the off-diagonal entries are $0$, you use the same cofactor expansion, but recognize that you're now computing the determinant of a matrix two of whose rows are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is basically to write 
$$
A\begin{pmatrix}C_{1,1}&...&C_{n,1}\\C_{1,2}&...&C_{n,2}\\\vdots\\C_{1,n}&...&C_{n,n}\end{pmatrix} = \det A\times I
$$using Cramer's theorem.